# Luis preBuilt entity personName - unexpected behaviour, missing basic name in utterance

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

In summary, why does Luis not label the preBuilt entity personName in some cases. Often the second name is not labeled for no discernible reason.
This behaviour does not exist for say geography preBuilt entity with the same kinds of utterances.
If anyone can explain why this happens and how best to address it I'd greatly appreciate it.
This simply dose not make sense to me. I would love to understand more.

personName Image here.
[Luis not labelling All personName correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejQfF.png)

geography example here (without the same issues as above)
[geography example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfd8R.png)

Thanks. K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario you described is currently the expected behavior (it might extract some or all names). However, we are working on improving the built-in personName entity (currently on our road-map). However, we recommend using a machine learned entity where you label the instances of names in your dataset and using the personName entity as a feature to help create your own name entity. Sorry for the inconvenience, but hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I am taking the approach as you mention to circumvent. But this is more of a bad release no? Anyways, I'll leave it with ye. Thanks for confirmation. K.